# How to change the stroke of a premade image?

Tags: gimp

I grabbed this PNG from the internet, but I don't like how thick its natural stroke is. Is there a way to make the stroke smaller even though I don't have the raw vector data for it?

[image]

Comment: I'm nto a Gimp user, so there may be a trick with that app. But generally raster images don't have "strokes". It's all pixels. So you can't target what *appears* to be a stroke and change its weight. You would need to select the transparency, expand the selection, then delete pixels around the exterior. Fairly easy to do, but your posted screenshot, with all its grays and checkerboard transparency indicator, makes it difficult for anyone to post images showing how with that particular image.

Comment: PNGs don't have strokes, they're a raster format. Everything is pixels. If you are up for it, get Inkscape (which is free and Open Source), and redraw it in vector. Then you can simply change the stroke width as desired. You might even be able to [find a vector file for free](https://thenounproject.com/search/icons/?iconspage=1&q=hand).

Comment: You can reconstruct the path. Google for "inkscape centerline".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the exterior of the hand (I used the fuzzy selection tool) and apply Select > Grow to select a part of the black stroke:

[image]

pressing DEL removes that part of the black which was in the expanded selection:

[image]

Better result is possible by deleting less from the outer side of the stroke and by making the white area bigger. In the next image the edge is thinned from outside 50% less, the white was selected, Select > Grow was applied and the selection was filled with white:

[image]

You must decide by yourself how much you want to cut from the outer edge and how much to expand the white interior.

The best result can be got by redrawing the shape in Inkscape - it's not a big deal when the shape is this simple (except in case one must start to use Inkscape from zero knowledge).

If the image has high enough resolution and it's free from JPG noise, tracing in Inkscape can create a good vector version. It unfortunately will have both black and white as filled areas, you cannot simply make the stroke narrower, because there's no strokes, only filled areas. But you can use Path > Dynamic Offset to make the white bigger and insert then black stroke. The original black area can be deleted. I unfortunately don't have good enough version for this route, I have only your low resolution screenshot, so I skip it.

Comment: Ahh my bad. But in actuality i meant inverse of what you did. Expand from white selection then invert selection to delete the part of the black. This has a less webbed selection.

Comment: That's a different idea. It may be useful. But it leaves a gap between the fingers.

Comment: @joojaa ditt bad fortsätter